# Using -- instead of value = value - 1 doesn't properly update .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to determine why I am getting the following behavior. Here is the div I am trying to update:

```
<h3 id='guess-count'> 5 Guesses Remaining </h3>
```

**Working Code:**

```
$('#guess-count').html(startingCount = startingCount - 1 + " Guesses Remaining");
```

This displays the updated value of the startingCount variable.

**Non-Working**

```
$('#guess-count').html(startingCount-- + " Guesses Remaining");
```

When I step in with debugger, I see the value does change but it isn't expressed in the html view.  However if I run this again, it does update the html value but to whatever value it is before it subtracts one.  Here is an example:

```
// starting value and first pass
startingCount = 5

 $('#guess-count').html(startingCount-- + " Guesses Remaining");

// startingCount html display value is 5 BUT startingCount holds the value of 4

startingCount = 4
//second pass
$('#guess-count').html(startingCount-- + " Guesses Remaining");

// startingCount html display value is 4 BUT startingCount holds the value of 3
```

It seems to be displaying the current value of startingCount, then subtracting one from its
value.

Does anybody know why this is acting this way? It appears it evaluates 'startingCount--' after it updates the html.

Comment: What happens if you use `--startingCount`?

Comment: You might want to read up on prefix and postfix for [arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the order of operation. Basically:

```
startingCount--
```

is saying *print the number and then decrement it.*

What you want is:

```
--startingCount
```

*decrement the number and then print it.*

Comment: _"print the number and then decrement it"_ - Perhaps nitpicky, but it's actually "decrement the number then return the previous/original value"

Comment: @JasonP I just though using the word *print* would be easier to understand than *return value* since he is updating the HTML.